# Como gerar um ID para identificar um aluno em uma base de dados com matriculas de vários anos?

Tags: python, pandas, data.frame, ciência-de-dados

Eu tenho a seguinte base de [dados](https://github.com/Renatolopo62/IFNMG-Januaria/blob/master/dados/dados_padronizados_matriculas_januaria_2009_2018.csv) que contem matriculas de uma Instituição que estou desenvolvendo uma pesquisa, futuramente para fazer um mapeamento dos alunos eu preciso de um id que identifique cada aluno, em que com esse id eu possa identificar o aluno no ano seguinte, já que eu tenho dados de 2009 a 2018.

Para criar esse id eu estou utilizando as colunas com os atributos dos alunos que não muda independente do ano, que no caso são `TP_COR_RACA`, `TP_SEXO`, `NU_ANO_NASCIMENTO`, `NU_MES_NASCIMENTO` e `NU_DIA_NASCIMENTO`, a ideia é que a partir desses atributos eu crie um
id que repete sempre que essa combinação for a mesma.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
def getKey(row):
    # retorna um str com os valores das colunas que são imutaveis independente do ano
    # que será usado como chave para gerar o Id.
    key = f"{row['TP_COR_RACA']}{row['TP_SEXO']}{row['NU_ANO_NASCIMENTO']}\
    {row['NU_MES_NASCIMENTO']}{row['NU_DIA_NASCIMENTO']}"

    return key

def getDicId(df):
    # retorna um dicionário em que os index são as chaves, sem repetir.
    dic_id = {}
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        key = getKey(row)
        dic_id[key] = 'null'

    # cria um id para cada chave do dicionario.
    idx = 1
    for i in dic_id:
        dic_id[i] = idx
        idx += 1

    return dic_id
 

def getId(df):
    df.loc[df_concat.TP_SEXO == 2, 'TP_SEXO'] = 0
    dic_id = getDicId(df)
    df['Id'] = 'null'
    # Obtem uma chave de cada matricula e atribui sue id usando  o 
    # dicionario que tem o index igual sua chave.
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        key = getKey(row)
        df.loc[index, 'Id'] = dic_id[key]
        
    return df
```

Porém não deu muito certo, o mesmo id foi gerado para alunos diferentes mesmo usado esses atributos como chave ao contrario do que eu esperava, o resultado pode ser conferido [aqui](https://github.com/Renatolopo62/IFNMG-Januaria/blob/master/dados/dados_padronizados_matriculas_januaria_2009_2018_com_id.csv), se alguém souber a onde está o erro ou de que outra forma eu possa fazer isso eu agradeço.

Comment: Em vez de criar um `ID` poderia ser mais conveniente utilizar o `CPF` do aluno, uma vez que, por natureza, o mesmo é intransferível e inalterável. Dessa forma, você pode acessar os dados do aluno, muitos anos após o mesmo ter deixado a instituição de ensino.

Comment: Seria uma boa mas não tem o CPF na base de dados

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema que deixe claro o que deu de errado na tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: @Bacco dei uma melhorada na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Carregando os dados:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Renatolopo62/IFNMG-Januaria/master/dados/dados_padronizados_matriculas_januaria_2009_2018.csv')
```

Convertendo o data frame todo para tipo string para poder manipular:

```
df1 = df.applymap(str)
```

Selecionando quais colunas irão gerar a nova coluna ID:

```
df1['ID']  = df1[['TP_COR_RACA', 
                 'TP_SEXO', 
                 'NU_ANO_NASCIMENTO',
                 'NU_MES_NASCIMENTO',
                 'NU_DIA_NASCIMENTO']].agg(''.join, axis=1)
```

Mostrando a coluna ID

```
df1['ID']
```

Saída:

```
0        311990613
1         60198987
2        601990130
3        611990119
4        101981816
           ...    
10982    321999117
10983     11199996
10984    321991615
10985    312000426
10986    321998121
```

Comment: Muito bem! consegui gerar dessa forma